# have two rows on flex. How can I make one relatively bigger than the other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have two elements (I mean columns) inside a flex row, I can make one relatively bigger than the other using the "flex" attribute in CSS. Something like this

```
.flexContainer {
  display:flex;

   .column1 {
      flex: 2;
   }

   .column2 {
      flex : 5;
   }
}
```

this way, column2 will be bigger than column 1 in that row.

I was trying to do the same, but instead of columns, with rows. Something like this:

```
.flexContainer {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;

   .row1 {
     flex:2;
    }

    .row2 {
       flex:5;
     }
}
```

but the rows have the same height. How can I make row2 be relatively bigger than row1? (relative to screen height)

Comment: it works the same for rows but you need to give a height to the container

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you show me the code that I would need to add?

Comment: as I said *give a height to the container*

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you know how I can give a height equal to the screen height?

Comment: `height:100vh` ........

Comment: @TemaniAfif cool thanks. This solves my question

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if flex has anything built in for this because it totally depends on the content you will provide. So:

1. You could give extra padding to `.row2` to give the illusion of different height.
2. You could instead use `display: grid` and create how ever many rows you want and for any given row, use `grid-row` to let it consume two rows worth of space instead of one.

For example, with this you are telling the row with class `row2` to consume both row 2 and 3 worth of space, giving it the difference in height you are looking for.

```
.row2 {
  grid-row: 2/span 3;
}
```

[More info here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)